# changing systemd service in RedHat 7

Tags: redhat, centos7, systemd

I wanted RedHat/CentOS 7, to do something after boot.
I change rhel-configure.service by editing the script called by that service: /lib/systemd/rhel-configure (& touch /.unconfigured) and add the line I wanted to perform after boot.

Nothing happen after boot. Also did not find anything in journalctl output.

How can I debug it or make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, when you want to execute a task at boot, you use the rc-local service.
Everything is explained here: http://www.certdepot.net/rhel7-configure-rc-local-service/